# flatpak: symbol lookup error: flatpak: undefined symbol: g_string_free_and_steal

Tags: linux, manjaro, flatpak

I accidentally uninstalled flatpak and on reinstalling it shows an error.
---- flatpak: symbol lookup error: flatpak: undefined symbol: g_string_free_and_steal ----

The option to enable flatpak support is missing in the software manager preferences.

On trying to install flatpak, It is shown that flatpak is installed and up to date.

As far as I can remember I haven’t done anything less.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.